# How to correctly do this css3 animation?

Tags: css

I have to animate a skip lorry. Trying to make the skip to move on the lorry but it does not happening correctly in the way it is to be.

The live preview is [here](http://codinglazy.com/test/). If you'll check it out then you'll understand what I'm saying and trying to do.
I'm making changes in skew() and rotate() but it turns out to be a bad job.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Animate Lorry</title>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<body>

  <div>

    <img class="sc" src="img/chain puller.png"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="animate" src="img/skip lorry.png"/>
  </div>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body{
    background-color: #000;
}
/*LORRY*/
.animate {
    padding: 100px;
    padding-left:400px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    /*-webkit-animation-name: lorry; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 15s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    animation-name: lorry;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;*/
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
/*@-webkit-keyframes lorry {
    0%   {right:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {right:500px; top:0px;}
    50%  {right:500px; top:0px;}
    75%  {right:500px; top:0px;}
    100% {right:500px; top:0px;}
}
*/
/*@keyframes lorry {
    0%   {right:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {right:500px; top:0px;}
    50%  {right:500px; top:0px;}
    75%  {right:500px; top:0px;}
    100% {right:500px; top:0px;}
}*/

/*SKIPHIRE*/
.contain {
    padding: 250px;
    padding-left: 445px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: container; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 


    animation-name: container;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes container {
    0%   {left:0px; bottom:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; bottom:0px;}
    50%  {left:200px; bottom:200px;}
    75%  {left:0px; bottom:200px;}
    100% {left:0px; bottom:150px;}
}

@keyframes container {
    0%   {left:0px; bottom:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; bottom:0px;}
    50%  {left:200px; bottom:200px;}
    75%  {left:0px; bottom:200px;}
    100% {left:0px; bottom:200px;}
}


.sc {
        width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 70px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 603px;
    position :absolute;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 5s  1 ease;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 5s  1 ease;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 5s  1 ease;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    } 

    @-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation 
    {
        from { -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }  
        to { -webkit-transform:  rotate(-15deg) scale(1) skew(-10deg) translate(-150px); } 
    } 

    @keyframes cssAnimation 
    {
        from { -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }  
        to { -webkit-transform:  rotate(-10deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(-150px); } 
    }
```

Tested in chrome only. But should be compatible for IE and Mozilla.

Comment: What are you trying to get though to stop at the top of the rail? or something more

Comment: I'm trying to achieve [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUBKE3dJEDs)

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation 
    {
        from { -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }  
        to { -webkit-transform:  rotate(-15deg) scale(1) skew(-10deg) translate(-150px); } 
        from { -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }  
        to { -moz-transform:  rotate(-15deg) scale(1) skew(-10deg) translate(-150px); } 
    } 

    @keyframes cssAnimation 
    {
        from { -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }  
        to { -webkit-transform:  rotate(-10deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(-150px); } 
        from { -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }  
        to { -moz-transform:  rotate(-10deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(-150px); } 
    }
```

Try this
-moz- = mozzila
-ms- = Internet explorer

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

scroll at the bottom of the page

**EDIT:**
I actually misread your question thought you didnt manage to make it work on IE and mozzila